# C# httpcookie is not being saved .net 3.5

Tags: c#, cookies, .net-3.5

I am having a lot of trouble trying to figure out why cookies I am creating in C# net 3.5 are not being saved.

On one page I have this code:

```
HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("LastPage");
myCookie.Domain = ".domain.com";
myCookie.Value = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30);
Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
```

On a different page I have this code to put all the cookies in a UL

```
        foreach (String thisKey in Request.Cookies.AllKeys)
        {
            HtmlGenericControl li = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
            HttpCookie thisCookie = Request.Cookies[thisKey];
            li.InnerHtml = thisCookie.Name + " = " + thisCookie.Value;
            ulCookies.Controls.Add(li);
        }
```

So why is it when I run the first page then run the second page in a different tab in the same browser, the cookie "LastPage" does not appear in the UL? I'm also unable to access the "LastPage" cookie on other pages.

I did notice that each time I reload the second page the ASP.NET_SessionId cookie is set to a different value. I think that is relevant to the issue, but I'm not sure.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is also in Visual Studio 2008 if that's a factor. I can get cookies to work Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: Are you running on single instance or Web Farm/Web Garden?

Comment: I think it's a single instance. I'm not sure if we're set up for a web farm/garden.

Comment: I found a solution. I had to rebuild the app using Visual Studio 2013. I guess there's a bug when it comes to cookies in 2008. Either that or cookies can't be set in when page.ispostback = true.